# In SVN Eclipse, what is the difference between "Update" and "Update to head"?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Eclipse with TortoiseSVN.
What is the difference between

1. I syncronize the project and "*Update*" on each file
2. click on the project and use Team > "*Update to head*"

If I create tag o other job, It's not the same activities of update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your first example updates just the files you have touched in your project or "view". In the second example your Team Update to Head revision will update the entire project from the top down, all files and folders and provide a Uniform revision number.

This post will explain it better. [Mark Phippard on SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209017/svn-synchronize-vs-update-to-head-subclipse)